# How do I use Thickbox to display videos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, thickbox

I'm trying to use thickbox to display a video on a page. Followed the instructions on the site but when I click on the link it just takes me to the youtube page which is not what I want.

I have the call to jquery and thickbox in my header, as well as the css for thick box:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/javascripts/thickbox.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/stylesheets/thickbox.css">
```

and here is the code in the body:

```
<strong>
<a class="thickbox" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/########?rel=0?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=400&width=600"  title="##### Hanson">
    <img src="http://www.#########.org/campaign/wp-content/uploads/sites/59/2013/09/#####.jpg"/>
</a> ##### Hanson*<br>(1960 B.S.M.E.)
</strong>
```

For the sake of privacy, I hashed some of the info in my code above. Any suggestions on what could be wrong?

Edit: Should probably mention I'm using this in word press

Comment: Side note (and unrelated to issue), you should put `<strong />` around `##### Hanson*<br>(1960 B.S.M.E.)` not the anchor itself. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the ThickBox `<script />` ***AFTER*** the jQuery file...like the code below.

**EDIT:** Also, replace the jQuery script you had with the CDN jQuery version, which I used in my example. Then clear your browser `cache` (important when working with WP).

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/javascripts/thickbox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/stylesheets/thickbox.css">
```

***As a rule of thumb***, your jQuery `<script />` should always be the first js file listed. It needs to load first before your other js scripts (assuming the rest of your scripts require jQuery). Otherwise they won't be initiated.

Comment: I switched the two around but it's still not working properly.

Comment: When you click the link...what happens? What console errors (In Chrome or Firebug) do you get AFTER you clicked the link?

Comment: I don't get any console errors in chrome after I click the link, it just takes me to the youtube page. Before I click the link though, console tells me:
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined       thickbox.js:14

Comment: In console, type `$.fn.jquery` and tell me it's result please.

Comment: Also, clear your browser cache, then try again. You're 100% sure the jQuery script is ABOVE the thichbox.js file, right?

Comment: The result was 1.8.2, however I just updated it to the most recent version just now.

I'm absolutely positive, unless our site host is experiencing some latency, it should be updated now.

Comment: Knew it...awesome. Glad to help!

Comment: In regards to your comment about using the CDN for jquery, if it were my choice, that's exactly what I would do. I've been talking to the guys I work with about just using the CDN's because we have multiple versions of jquery in multiple folders. It's ridiculous and needs to stop especially since it's just better practice to use CDN's. Also thanks for your help.

Comment: Agreed! Most browsers have jQuery cached anyways as well...so why use your own server resources when someone else will? :)